# How do I work with a Sprite Sheet in Cocos2d iPhone?

Tags: iphone, animation, cocos2d-iphone, sprite-sheet

I have a sprite sheet PNG sent to me by an artist. Inside the sprite sheet, there are 4 sprites, each 32x32, and they make an animation. I want to be able to have a CCSprite on screen, who goes through the animation. I've tried all kinds of things, but truth be told, I really just don't understand the concept of Sprite Sheets. I'm seeing all kinds of things around the web of needing property lists and such. All I got from my artist is a simple PNG. 
Please help?

Comment: The property list thing is just a list of all of your frames and their locations and sizes inside of the image. Since you don't have that plist, you need to specify each rect manually. There is a method, I believe, that allows you to specify such a rect. [CCSprite spriteWithFile:rect:]; Either that, or create new sprite frames and add them to the sprite frame cache.

Comment: Honestly, it would be so much easier on you if you could have the artist send you the four 32x32 images as separate files. Then download a program such as [TexturePacker](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker) (you don't have to pay for basic functionality). With that, you can easily generate the sprite sheet PNG and associated plist in the easiest possible manner.

Comment: @Corbin87 If you post an answer, I'd upvote it if you comment to me. I was going to suggest TexturePacker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had this problem and this is the solution I came up with,
no plists and no Zwoptex needed,
but this assumes each frame is exactly 32x32 and perfectly aligned at 32 intervals.

```
@interface GameLevelLayer() 
{
    CCSpriteBatchNode *trexSheet;
    int aniCount;
    NSTimer *autoWalker;


}
@end
```

in your init or wherever add the spritesheet

```
trexSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"dinosss.png"];
[self addChild:trexSheet];
aniCount=1;
```

Use an NSTimer to stop and Start an animation

```
-(void)stopWalker{
        aniCount =1;
//set to start frame
    [self.player setDisplayFrame:
[CCSpriteFrame frameWithTexture:trexSheet.texture rect:
CGRectMake(0,0,32,32)]];

    if (autoWalker){   
    [autoWalker invalidate];
    autoWalker = nil;
    }

}
```

and to start...

```
-(void)startWalker{

if (!autoWalker){ 
   [self walkimate];
    //Change the timeInterval to adjust animation speed
    autoWalker = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.15
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(walkimate)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
} 
}
```

the looped function

```
-(void)walkimate{
    ///loop through animation
if (aniCount>4) {
    ///set to 0 because we add one at the end before the next call
    aniCount =0;
}

//this finds the 32x32 pa
[self.player setDisplayFrame:
[CCSpriteFrame frameWithTexture:trexSheet.texture rect:
CGRectMake(32*i,0,32,32)];

aniCount++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Zwoptex tool to export spriteSheet with cocos2D plist. Its free tool and easy to use.